# Stop PL/SQL code after exception (PL/SQL, ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, oracle12c

I have check procedure:

```
PROCEDURE checkVariables                               
IS
   r_Var1    exception;
   r_Var2    exception;
BEGIN

 If g_Name is null then     
        RAISE r_Var1;
 End if;
 If g_Prefix is null then     
        RAISE r_Var2;
 End if;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Variables Set Up');

 EXCEPTION
        When r_Var1 then
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing g_Name');               
        When r_Var2 then
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing g_Prefix');            
END;
```

If the exception is raised I want beside message also STOP/BREAK all other PL/SQL code (procedure procedure 3 and 4 will be not executed).

like:

```
execute procedure1
execute procedure2
execute checkVariables --raised exception, STOP/BREAK next code                               
execute procedure3
execute procedure4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Wrap them in another procedure, change exception response as a variable out from proc, raise exception on outer proc based on variable

Comment: can you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-raise the exception from your `checkVariables` procedure. Run all your procedures inside a `BEGIN..END` with an `EXCEPTION` block

```
...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN r_var1 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing g_Name');
             RAISE; 

  WHEN r_var2 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Missing g_Prefix');
             RAISE;
END;
...
```

---

```
BEGIN

  procedure1;
  procedure2;
  checkVariables; --raised exception, STOP/BREAK next code                               
  procedure3;
  procedure4; 

EXCEPTION

WHEN  OTHERS THEN 

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EXCEPTION  OCCURED');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()); --Gives additional information

END;
/
```

**Output**  would be something like this.

```
PROC1
PROC2
Missing g_Name
EXCEPTION  OCCURED
ORA-06512: at "HR.CHECKVARIABLES", line 21
ORA-06512: at "HR.CHECKVARIABLES", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Comment: thanks, I have also added ROLLBACK: when it's failed and when it success